# Is IPv4 header checksum required?

Tags: ip

Resources online say that UDP checksum is optional and can be all zeros if unused.  Does the same go for IPv4 header checksum?  Or is that absolutely required i.e. must be correct all the time?

Based on a couple tests, I can't just put 0xDEADBEEF -or- 0x00000000 in the IPv4 header checksum and see a packet in Wireshark; it appears to get discarded.  I haven't read anything that mentions all zeros as an indicator that the IPv4 header checksum is disabled like in UDP (but I haven't read anything to the contrary either).

Comment: This isn't an InfoSec problem, as presented. If you can change the checksum to 0xDEADBEEF, why can't you run the same experiment with all zeros? If you checked resources online for UDP, why not look for TCP, too? The top 3 results in Google all point to the answer that it is required.

Comment: @schroeder Put my question here since it seemed OT for StackOverflow.  Is there another exchange that I should have used?  Also, top 3 answers on Google for "ipv4 checksum" do not mention anything about it being required or not.  gowefawr's Wikipedia link isn't clear that the initial checksum (before a router) needs to be correct; it just basically says that there is a checksum.  It seems only the RFC gave the details I needed, and I am not familiar with how to search that (Google didn't bring up the RFC page).

Comment: There is a [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) exchange. Google "ipv4 checksum required" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPv4 header checksum **must be correct or the packet will be discarded** by the next device that processes it:

> The Header Checksum provides a verification that the information used
> in processing internet datagram has been transmitted correctly.  The
> data may contain errors.  If the header checksum fails, the internet
> datagram is discarded at once by the entity which detects the error.

([RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791))

> At each hop, the checksum is recalculated and the packet will be
> discarded upon checksum mismatch. The router must adjust the checksum
> if it changes part of the IP header (such as when decrementing the
> TTL.)

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum))

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't sure where to look in the RFCs to find that